# Cannot build lldb - 'atomic' file not found

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors, clang, lldb

I'm trying to build `lldb` that's part of Clang/LLVM's 3.4.2 downloads at [LLVM Download Page](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html).

I can build LLVM, Clang, Compiler-RT and Extras. However, when I add LLDB to my recipe, the build fails:

```
llvm[3]: Compiling lldb.cpp for Release+Asserts build
llvm[3]: Compiling lldb-log.cpp for Release+Asserts build
In file included from /Users/jeffrey/Clang-3.4.2/llvm/tools/lldb/source/lldb-log.cpp:10:
In file included from /Users/jeffrey/Clang-3.4.2/llvm/tools/lldb/source/../include/lldb/lldb-private-log.h:17:
In file included from /Users/jeffrey/Clang-3.4.2/llvm/tools/lldb/source/../include/lldb/lldb-private.h:19:
In file included from /Users/jeffrey/Clang-3.4.2/llvm/tools/lldb/source/../include/lldb/lldb-public.h:13:
In file included from /Users/jeffrey/Clang-3.4.2/llvm/tools/lldb/source/../include/lldb/lldb-defines.h:13:
In file included from /Users/jeffrey/Clang-3.4.2/llvm/tools/lldb/source/../include/lldb/lldb-types.h:14:
In file included from /Users/jeffrey/Clang-3.4.2/llvm/tools/lldb/source/../include/lldb/lldb-forward.h:15:
/Users/jeffrey/Clang-3.4.2/llvm/tools/lldb/source/../include/lldb/Utility/SharingPtr.h:22:10: fatal error: 
      'atomic' file not found
#include <atomic>
         ^
In file included from /Users/jeffrey/Clang-3.4.2/llvm/tools/lldb/source/lldb.cpp:12:
In file included from /Users/jeffrey/Clang-3.4.2/llvm/tools/lldb/source/../include/lldb/lldb-private.h:19:
In file included from /Users/jeffrey/Clang-3.4.2/llvm/tools/lldb/source/../include/lldb/lldb-public.h:13:
In file included from /Users/jeffrey/Clang-3.4.2/llvm/tools/lldb/source/../include/lldb/lldb-defines.h:13:
In file included from /Users/jeffrey/Clang-3.4.2/llvm/tools/lldb/source/../include/lldb/lldb-types.h:14:
In file included from /Users/jeffrey/Clang-3.4.2/llvm/tools/lldb/source/../include/lldb/lldb-forward.h:15:
/Users/jeffrey/Clang-3.4.2/llvm/tools/lldb/source/../include/lldb/Utility/SharingPtr.h:22:10: fatal error: 
      'atomic' file not found
#include <atomic>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

LLDB was unpacked next to Clang as requested per [Building LLDB](http://lldb.llvm.org/build.html):

```
llvm
|
`-- tools
    |
    +-- clang
    |
    `-- lldb
```

LLDB is being built in a build directory as requested (as is everything else):

```
mkdir build
cd build
../llvm/configure --enable-optimized --prefix=/usr/local
make -j4
```

I found a similar issue discussed at [LLDB @ Mac OSX: build on Snow Leopard (still) supported?](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/lldb-dev/2014-February/003241.html). However, the suggested solution is to turn some knobs with `xcodebuild` from the command line. I'm not using Xcode, so its not an alternative for me.

My environment is OS X 10.8.5, x64, fully patched. Xcode version 5.1.1 (5B1008). I have Clang 3.4.2 installed in `usr/local/` (without `lldb`), but I don't believe its being used.

How does one build lldb from the command line?

Comment: Based on Icaru's answer, I think part of the solution is `--enable-cxx11 --enable-libcpp`. Its not clear to me why `configure` did not configure itself properly since these are *needed*, and not optional. Its only partial because there are more problems: [Undefined symbols SystemRuntimeMacOSX::Initialize and SystemRuntimeMacOSX::Terminate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923650/undefined-symbols-systemruntimemacosxinitialize-and-systemruntimemacosxtermi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add "--enable-cxx11" switch while running "configure" script.

By default c++11 is disabled.

For more information run "configure --help"

Comment: Thanks Icarus. That died even quicker with `no member named 'move' in namespace 'std'; did you mean simply 'move'?`. Damn I hate working with Apple's junk. I really miss Windows and Linux....

Comment: I *think* I need `--enable-cxx11 --enable-libcpp`. But I'm not certain because there are more errors I'm trying to work trough.

Answer (score 0):

You must use both --enable-libcpp --enable-cxx11 for configuring an llvm build with lldb included. However, if you are trying to build with 3.4, you'll run into another issue. See this question here for a way to resolve this.

[Undefined symbols SystemRuntimeMacOSX::Initialize and SystemRuntimeMacOSX::Terminate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923650/undefined-symbols-systemruntimemacosxinitialize-and-systemruntimemacosxtermi)