# How to use -enable-cxx11 flag in cgo

Tags: c++, go, cgo

I am trying to run C++ code inside my go code. I figured out that I need `-enable-cxx11` flag during compilation (because otherwise I get an error like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909597/cannot-build-lldb-atomic-file-not-found)).

But somehow flags do not work:

```golang
/*
#cgo CPPFLAGS: -enable-cxx11
#include "cPackage/create_hyper_file_from_csv.cpp"
*/
import "C"
```

How do I use this flag?

Comment: I'd assume to provide it as command line argument, have you tried `go tool cgo -enable-cxx11`?

Comment: unfortunately that does not work `flag provided but not defined: -enable-cxx11`

Comment: Next attempt: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51109843/1312382 – I'd try both, identically as is or replacing `-std=c++11` with the flag in question – and finally both flags combined. If it's not that, I'm out of ideas, no go specialist...